# Why didn't Doctor Strange give this information to Tony before dying on Titan?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame

The only reason The Avengers got screwed and

> Iron Man

had to die was because they

> sent Nebula back in time.

At the end of *Avengers: Infinity War*, why didn't Doctor Strange simply tell Tony to not send Nebula back in time?

Comment: I'm gonna get bored of answering your questions with _"Because things had to play out exactly as they did to be in the one winning scenario"_.

Answer (score 7):

## Because that was not the winning scenario

As Doctor Strange says himself they only win in one scenario, the one we see, for that to happen things had to play out exactly as we saw them. If they didn't then they wouldn't win.

> **Doctor Strange:** I went forward in time to view alternate futures. To see all the possible outcomes of the coming conflict.
>
> **Peter Quill:** How many did you see?
>
> **Doctor Strange:** 14,000,605.
>
> **Tony Stark:** How many did we win?
>
> **Doctor Strange:** One.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

Then in *Endgame* Strange refuses to tell Stark if they're in the winning outcome telling him that if he does it won't happen. As such we can assume that he couldn't tell Tony that on Titan for the same reason... which is true had Nebula not gone back things wouldn't have happened the way they did.

> **Tony Stark:** You said one out of 14 million, we win, yeah? Tell me this is it.
>
> **Doctor Strange:** If I tell you what happens, it won't happen.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

Comment: I will provide more information about this answer.
As it is the only way to succeed, things could have gone wrong if Nebula was not here in the past. She was essential to the catch of the Power stone, as she knows where to find Quill, open the temple and retrieve the stone. If she wasn't there maybe War Machine couldn't suceed this part.

And as Ant-man said during the movie :

"We have enough Pim Particule for one travel each and a test drive"

Comment: @TinyDoowy They knew the coordinates. Rocket could have accompanied War Machine.

Comment: Thus Rocket lets Thor alone on Asgard where he probably messed everything up alone because he was in a really bad shape a that moment. There's only one out of millions possibilities that works.